# Facebook, Yimg and google-analytics CDNs is freaking me out

Tags: facebook, windows-vista, cdn

Its been a couple of weeks that some sites just keeps on hanging.

e.g.
Facebooks => static.ak.fbcdn.net
FLicker => l.yimg.com
GoogleAnalytics

I've googled and found many problems like this and some answers which are outdated or just doesn't solve the problem.
I did:
Cookies clearing, ran cc cleaner and several other nifty methods. None solved my problem??

Only with facebook, if I enter https:// manually instead of http:// on every url on facebook, it works and when it does the redirection to http://, everytime I have to type 's' on the address bar to make it https://

It is driving me nuts coz I'm developing Facebook App and this problem in being pain in my ass.

What might be the reason for these CDNs hanging behaviour??

**Update: Mon Feb 8, 2010**
Well when I viewed the source with firefox, this is the header part:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zDO0B/hash/8jpbog60.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zA96O/hash/8jqnsh63.css" />

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z9X8U/hash/5zy5e7ns.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z7XWB/hash/b881ctjq.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zEMLE/hash/6n3druoq.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zEEQQ/hash/3et16vbl.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zF0BN/hash/4ey03a8b.css" />
#<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zD46U/hash/4ctxkmr7.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z5KPU/hash/f92tjc5l.js"></script>
```

When I clicked the each link, all links open with its contents except the last link with -# sign prefixed.
So the url `-#http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zD46U/hash/4ctxkmr7.css` is not opening and this css file is not downloaded and the facebook page looks horrible and all left aligned??

**Update: Tue Feb 9, 2010**
Today the link with the -# sign is just keeps hanging and looping:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zEMLE/hash/6n3druoq.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z9X8U/hash/5zy5e7ns.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zF0BN/hash/4ey03a8b.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z1580/hash/4l5utauj.css" />

#<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z4851/hash/532htj7z.css" />

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z1GEW/hash/dh01t0zv.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z80UK/hash/3a6o59ih.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zD46U/hash/4ctxkmr7.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z5KPU/hash/f92tjc5l.js"></script>
```

Why that url http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net acting weird? Has something Akamai got to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

It could be some kind of connectivity issue between you and the CDNs. Blocking them with adblock (or the hosts file) is an effective way forward, or there's a Firefox extension for it - [Ghostery.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9609)

Comment: Thats not the case. I installed Ghostery and its fine that its tracking Google and Disquss on many pages. Actually, its not the problem with my Firefox only, its the same for all browsers Opera, IE, Chrome, FF, Safari..

Answer (score 0):

This could also be an issue with your ISP.  I have seen cases in which certain domains take arduous amounts of time to access or, in some cases, cannot be accessed at all during peak hours.  It could be possible that the domains you're having issues with are ones that your ISP is having problems with.  In the past I've experienced outages of Google as well as one or tow subdomains.

Do you have the same problem from different computers on the same network?

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. I've not resolved the issue completely but I found a hack fix:
Set the CDN domains to fixed IP numbers in your local computer's hosts file.

I added these lines to my WinXP `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` 
Other OS's have a similar file(Linux: `/etc/hosts`)

`# CDN networks broken for Yahoo, Google and Facebook

217.212.252.78  static.ak.fbcdn.net

217.212.252.78  profile.ak.fbcdn.net

217.212.252.78  external.ak.fbcdn.net

217.212.252.78  creative.ak.fbcdn.net

217.212.252.78  platform.ak.fbcdn.net

217.212.252.78  l.yimg.com`

To choose the fastest IPs for your location visit just-ping.com .

I've not tried it but this trick might also work for Windows users:
  http://www.updatexp.com/dns-windows-xp.html

Answer (score 0):

I observed this same issue on several computers on our home LAN over a prolonged period and after many months, finally found a fix. It turned out that the intrusion detection rules in my Billion ADSL router were overly aggressive in blocking sites.  This discussion thread revealed the issue and solution for my case.

http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1622370

You may find that your router has similar issues or that your firewall performs a similar intrusion detection function that needs tuning.

If you have a similar router or firewall feature, you can test if this is the case by clearing the 'intrusion detection' blacklist when you observe the blocking problem to see if it unblocks the site.

If you have a Billion modem/router, I'd also recommend updating to the latest firmware that now includes the ability to add white list IPs that will permanently prevent IP blocking.  This may or may not be helpful for CDN sites like Facebook that use large server farms (= numerous IPs per domain name). What I think Billion need to do here is support domain name white listing rather than just IP white listing so that the router determines which IP you've been allocated for this domain.